# select where the first character is numeric

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a query that should return title's that begin with 0-9 or a-z, depending on what is requested. I have an index on the `title` column so for the individual letters I'm doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE 'a%';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE 'b%';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE 'c%';
/* etc... */
```

For the numbers, however, it doesn't really matter which number it is, it only matters that the first character is numeric. I want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '0%'
                       OR title LIKE '1%';
                       OR title LIKE '2%';
                       OR title LIKE '3%';
/* etc... */
```

But this feels a little sloppy. To my understanding regex won't really work well with an index, and I'm not sure about string functions. Would something like `WHERE SUBSTRING(title,1,1) IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` still take advantage of the index or is there a more compact way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your characters are all "ASCII", then you can do:

```
where title >= '0' and title < ':'
```

This should be able to use an index.

I admit the meaning is a bit elusive, but the colon is the first ASCII character after `'9'`.

Comment: Nice and simple solution. +1

Comment: where title >= '0' and title <= '9'

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't think so... It's a slight variation of yours. Did you try it?

Comment: @YesMan . . . The previous comment should have been:  "That would NOT return `'99'`.

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon is correct in that all ascii strings are between '0' and ':'

The same is true for the queries with letters, all string between 'a' and '{' will match.

Regarding the second part of your question, if `WHERE SUBSTRING(title,1,1) IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` will use an index, the answer is no. When the column from the index is used in a function, `SUBSTRING` in this case, it has to apply the function to all values in the table, always making a full table scan.